# Push notification certificate P12 file

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, push-notification

What does a Push Certificate P12 file contains -- Private or Public key? Any detail on this will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must contain both public and private key for push notifications to work.

[Installing the SSL Certificate and Key on the Server](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW6)

Answer (score 0):

It depends from how you exported it from keychain. Certificate by it's own is public key. If you exported from Keychain both Certificate+private key, than .p12 will contain them both.

Answer (score 0):

you will need it to be a pem file for it to work.. the should be some scripts out there to convert p12 files to pem files.